# Why is I am getting "None" for batch size after training and make a prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, probability, distribution, tf.keras

I understand that before running TF graph the batch_size can be "None" but it should be replaced by actual batch_size after training and make a prediction. Here my codes, i used an LSTM and then make the output to distribution layeres.

```
input = tf.keras.Input((6,1), name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(200)(input)
print (x.shape)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)

output = tfpl.DistributionLambda(
        lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1),
        convert_to_tensor_fn=lambda s: s.sample(5))(x)
print (output.shape, "output.shape")

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)

negloglik = lambda y, p_y: -p_y.log_prob(y)


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
model.compile(loss=negloglik,optimizer=optimizer)
print (model.summary())
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=300, verbose=1)

predt = model.predict(X_train,verbose=0)
# extracting the last ouptput (also = the last hidden state)
print (predt.shape)

# After printing predt the shape is TensorShape([15, None, 1]).
```

For some data for example it works but for others it gives None as above.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. The `output.shape` will always show `None` even after training, because the batch size may change. However, the shape of the output of `model.predict` should not be `None`. I tried your code and everything makes sense. Would you please elaborate more?

Comment: Thanks, it seems i resolved the issue. I used model(X_train) instead of model.predict(X_train) and now the model prediction is not None and has the batch_size number. It seems there is a slight diff between these two